# How to resolve problem with two versions of Google Earth installed from different sources? 

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, google-earth

both I installed Google Earth 6.1 several months ago. I've just install GE 6.2 this evening by downloading the .deb package on the Google site. After the download, GE installed fine with the Software Center. I found GE 6.2 with the Unity lens and drag + drop on the Unity launcher. GE opens and seems to work fine.

But the issue is that I still have 6.1 on my computer, I thought it had been upgraded automatically to 6.2. I can find 6.1 on the software center as it says it is installed, but I can't find any 6.2. I open synaptic and can find 6.1 but not 6.2.

So my questions are: How do I uninstall 6.1 without breaking 6.2? Why is there no trace of 6.2 on my machine? Where is 6.2 installed on my hard drive, as 6.1 is on my `home/.googleearth` directory?

First thanks to everyone for taking time to answer.

Synaptic is already in my computer and I can now understand as I see the 2 packages related to Google Earth.

GE 6.2 is in a package called **google-earth-stable** and the older version is in a package called **googleearth** (see attached picture). What I still don't understand is that in Unity's Dash Menu I can see **google-earth-stable** and **googleearth** but in the Install Software tab of the Software Center, I can't see any trace of **google-earth-stable** installation or **googleearth**? Perhaps this is because there are not Software but packages?
http://ubuntuone.com/06x7QZoWJXPE72Ceo5XCU7

Can I safely unistall **googleearth** without braking **google-earth-stable** via the Software Center?

Also I saw that in the snapshot that **googleearth** (older, v. 6.1) has a version of 6.0.3.2197+0.6.0-1 and the **google-earth-stable** (newer, v. 6.2) has a version of 6.1.0.5001-r0. Why is it that the product version numbers don't match the packge version numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you downloaded the .debs directly from Google the Ubuntu Software Center doesn't have a "Repository" available to check version information against. Repositories are a nice way of keeping everything well organized and have the benefit of automagically updating things. Repositories organize software into what are called packages, and these all have a unique name.

It is possible that Google gave the new version of google earth a new name, thus allowing them to both be on your computer at the same time, even if one overwrote most of the files from the other (or was prevented from doing so because of the existing package).

The easiest way to sort this all out is to see what packages are installed on your computer. Since newer versions of Ubuntu don't have synaptic installed by default you can either do option A, which requires no new software to be installed. Or option B which requires a painless install of synaptic.

Press Control+Shift+T to open a terminal

#### Option A

Run this, then copy and paste the results into your question (use four spaces to indent each line):

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i google
```

This lists all the packages installed on the computer (`dpkg -l`) and then filters out all the ones that don't have the word Google in them (`grep -i google`). The `sudo` gives you super-user/root privileges and the pipe `|` feeds the output of one command into the input for the second.

#### Option B

Run this: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`. This installs the synpatic package which will allow you to see and install packages without having to use a command line (I prefer them really). There is a search box near the top, plug in 'google' and then maximize the window. Screen shot the results, get them online, and link to them in your question.

Comment: Didn't the OP already mention using synaptic in the question?

Comment: Indeed, it seems he did. I saw Ubuntu Software Center in the first paragraph, but missed the last line of the second. In that case, I'd recommend that he just straight to `dpkg`. Failing that I'd have to replicate the setup. Maybe he has the old deb somewhere I could pick apart.

Comment: I suppose synaptic still on my computer because I haven't make any clean install since Ubuntu 10.04, currently running 11.10.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot you posted I can say it is 99% safe to uninstall **googlearth** by clicking the green box next to it and selecting "mark for removal" and then hitting the green check box at the top. (alternately, on the command line `sudo apt-get remove -y googleearth`)

Comment: The reason that the product version numbers and the package version  numbers don't match up is purely marketing. Users like to see revision numbers go up significantly, even it only minor changes were actually made.

Comment: uninstall googlearth via synaptique works OK and google-earth-stable works fine. problem solved, thanks.